# How to store large number of Audio Files in Android?

Tags: android, audio

I am working on an application which requires me to play large number of audio files. Each file would be of size 100KB approximately. Currently i have 220 files which can go up in future. If I put these files in res/raw folder then i would end up having a very large size of APK file.

What are the best methods to store audio files in android?
What type of audio file would be best to store in the apk?
Or Please suggest me some other approach to deal with such a large number of audio files.

Comment: What are the audio quality requirements? Are they all static, or can they be updated without updating the app?

Comment: Audio quality is not that important. One should be able to hear tones. No it will be updated when there is an app update.

Comment: Putting all the sounds in one file and playing/extracting audio starting at a certain offset in the file should save some space in the file system.

Answer (score 3):

There is 50MB limit on main APK.

If I were you I would include only "required" files and then use Android Expansion files: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html to download additional ones.