# How to store lots of audio file in Android

Tags: android, audio, storage

I need to store a large number of audio files in my app (around 350/400 files ).  Each file has an average size of 2MB. I really don't know where to store them. Should i use SQLite database ? external storage ? something else ?

There will be no update on these files, i just want to store them and then play them. Currently i have like 15 files in the res/raw folder and it's really slow at launching.

My question is similar to this one: [How to store large number of Audio Files in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651455/how-to-store-large-number-of-audio-files-in-android) but i didn't get the answer.

Thanks

Comment: The answer is as explained there - you either use the Expansion mechanism, or some comparable custom solution & server.  This is simply too much data to distribute in your apk itself.

Comment: Presumably these are already stored in a compressed audio format; if not they should be.  Even if they are, you could perhaps contemplate using a lowerer bitrate encoding for a more compact result, though it will still be large enough to be a problem without an elegant solution.

Comment: Ok i'll have a look at the expansion mechanism, and you are right i should start by compressing them, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need store in another place like the SD card. Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 50MB. You need 800MB for my math.

Check this link:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 1):

You should store them in the External storage directory, unless this app is for your personal phone, and you know you have enough space.

The reason is many phones produced in the past few years have virtually no internal storage space (e.g. my nexus S has 1g internal, 15g external).

As others have said, you would have to use an [Expansion File](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) to distribute via Google Play, and this is by default downloaded to an External Directory.  You cannot move, delete, or rename these files.  Thus, I don't think its possible to store them internally (unless you make a redundant copy).

If the files are zip, you can access the media in these expansion files directly (and that is the Android's recommended approach).

If you do unpack and copy the media, you should probably store the data as seperate files.  There's a number of database concerns to look into if you store large blob data (e.g. gigabytes) in SQlite.  You can use a database to store any metadata for your music, by associating it with the file name/location.  But if you just want to just store music, the file system is enough.

If you want your music to be accessible by other apps, use the built in Android directory for music (code below), o/w store it under android/data/com.name.package.

```
public File getMusicStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.


    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all these clarifications, yeah i read that internal storage is not a solution due to space problem. As for SQLite, there is no use of it because all i do is store and get the music, there is no other action right ?  So from what you said i should go with the expansion files.

Comment: Unless you decide to store metadata then a database becomes useful, e.g. users favorites, collections, e.g. genre, arists, etc.  But you just store the metadata there, and some id that relates to the actual file (or offset in the expansion file).

Answer (score -2):

IMHO you MUST use sqlite DB, there aren't many other options.. Maybe you can think about cloud storage and streaming for play. But this will going to complicate stuffs. Try out the sql lite solution, here [ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html ] you can implement it in a couple of minutes. Cheers!